# Is there a way to not get duplicates?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering what I am doing wrong. I'm writing a python program that converts my "joke-made" programming language into python. I always get this weird mess.
This is my code

```
#input file
inputfile = input("Filename > ")
print("""
Available Languages:
Python
""")
langsel = input("Select > ")
fin = open(f"{inputfile}", "rt")
#output file to write the result to
fout = open(f"{inputfile}.py", "wt")
#for each line in the input file
if langsel == "Python":
    for line in fin:
        fout.write(line.replace('printiln(', 'print('))
        fout.write(line.replace('rinput(', 'input('))
        fout.write(line.replace('printiln("', 'print("'))
        fout.write(line.replace("printiln('", "print('"))

else:
    print("Invalid Language")
#close input and output files
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

I used this file as a test:

```
printiln("Are you sure? ")
rinput("Yes or No? ")
```

Python puts out this file when running the program:

```
print("Are you sure? ")
printiln("Are you sure? ")
print("Are you sure? ")
printiln("Are you sure? ")
rinput("Yes or No? ")
input("Yes or No? ")
rinput("Yes or No? ")
rinput("Yes or No? ")
```

I want my output to be:

```
print("Are you sure? ")
input("Yes or No? ")
```

Comment: What do you want the output to be? Your output looks as expected to me. You execute four `fout.write` calls for every line in your input file.

Comment: @HåkenLid I want the output to be print(Are you sure? ") and input("Yes or No? ")
I don't want it duplicating 5 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get four output lines per input line because you have four writes in your `for` block.

```
for line in fin:
    fout.write(line.replace('printiln(', 'print('))
    fout.write(line.replace('rinput(', 'input('))
    fout.write(line.replace('printiln("', 'print("'))
    fout.write(line.replace("printiln('", "print('"))
```

Make sure you only write a single line for each input line. For example, you can do this.

```
for line in fin:
    line = line.replace('printiln(', 'print(')
    line = line.replace('rinput(', 'input(')
    fout.write(line)  # single write to output file
```